# A word that describes a word for which there are no words

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I have searched the internet, read every dictionary and scanned website after website, and cannot find a word that describes a word for which there are presently, in your language, no words. Does such a word exist.

Is there a word or term that means a word that doesn't exist in a language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[A word for "lack of a word"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249146/a-word-for-lack-of-a-word)*, itself closed as a duplicate of *[What would you call a word that doesn't exist in or translate well into another language?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138289)*. The short answer is that *gap* or *lacuna* will do the job, but since these words have other and more common uses, *lexical gap* may be preferable.

Comment: It`s not a single word, but I believe that the term "lexical gap" properly describes this situation

Comment: @Michael Alig : I find it quite impressive that you've "read every dictionary."  You're eyes and brain must be quite tired.

Comment: Is there a word for the absence of the Oxford comma? ;)

Comment: The word should be "anomaly," but "anomaly" doesn't mean that, making "anomaly" a misnomer.

Comment: @Tim Ward: A Cambridge Commaspiracy? :P